# linux message other users' terminal: change text color?

Tags: linux, unix, colors, message

When a user sends my terminal text with `write user [ttyname]` command in linux/unix, is there a way to `trap` or capture that text automatically written to my terminal and change it's color so it's more obvious?

From `man write`:

`Write allows you to communicate with other users, by copying lines from your terminal to theirs.`

I've added an alias so when I use `write` my text changes color, i.e.:

`alias write='echo -e "\033[1;31m\c" ; write '`

But that simply changes all text on the terminal.

Essentially, I want an easy way to read text that is being sent to my terminal from another user. Any advice?

I've tried setting `trap` with all the signals from 1-60 but nothing seems to catch the text?

Answer (score 0):

You could only capture that text if it were written to your shell's *input*.  The terminal is in a different direction (your shell's *output*).  There are other programs which are designed to make the text more visible as well as logging the session (look for `irc` clients).

Without some (relatively) smart server in between, all that you normally get from [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/write.html) (or [`talk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/talk.html)) is low-level stuff that the terminal driver can handle without coordinating the appearance of messages.  You *could* write messages directly to the user's pseudoterminal special devices using the `/proc` filesystem (and knowing the process-id).

On Linux, a given process can refer to itself using `/dev/stdin`, etc., which are symbolic links to the `/proc` filesystem, e.g.,

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root           15 Fri 04:19:34   stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root           15 Fri 04:19:34   stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root           15 Fri 04:19:34   stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
```

If you know the process-id of the other user's terminal *and* have permission, you can manipulate those as well.  (If it is a different user, you probably do not have permission — that is the point of those other programs, which *can* be granted the permissions).

Further reading:

- [How to read/write to tty* device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138342/how-to-read-write-to-tty-device)
- [8.2. Catching user input](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) (Bash Guide for Beginners)
- [Understanding /dev and its subdirs and files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18239/understanding-dev-and-its-subdirs-and-files)
- [Solving problems with proc](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/solving_problems_with_proc)